# in-app update restarting the obsolete version instead of the newly installed version

Tags: java, android, in-app-update

I want to implement the in-app update. With the following code, it correctly prompts the user to ask him to agree with the update, downloads the code and installs it. But then the system restarts the **previously installed** version of the application and again goes through the update process. What's wrong with the following code?

In the `onCreate()` method:

```
        appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);
        Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();
        appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
            if (mPrefs == null) {
                mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("******" + appName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            }
            int updateRequestCounter = mPrefs.getInt("updateRequestCounter", 0);

            if ((updateRequestCounter == 0) || (updateRequestCounter == 5) || (updateRequestCounter % 10 == 0)) {
                if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE) {
                    switch (appUpdateInfo.installStatus()) {
                        case InstallStatus.FAILED: case InstallStatus.REQUIRES_UI_INTENT: case InstallStatus.UNKNOWN:
                            try {
                                appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                                        appUpdateInfo,
                                        AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                                        this,
                                        MY_REQUEST_CODE);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                mPrefs.edit().putInt("updateRequestCounter", 0).apply();

            } else {
                mPrefs.edit().putInt("updateRequestCounter", ++updateRequestCounter).apply();
            }
    });
```

No idea whether it can be the cause: I use this code not with a *production* version but with an *internal test* version of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the update installation part.
You need to call `appUpdateManger.completeUpdate()` to install the update. AppUpdateManager will relaunch the app for you.

Test the update installation in release version of your app.

Comment: The documentation says that in case of an IMMEDIATE update, "Google Play handles the update installation and app restart". I indeed get the download and installation screens as shown in the documentation. However it then restarts the obsolete version, not the just installed one.

Comment: Then I think you are testing the update in a debug version of the app.

Comment: Yes, I tried different combinations and it turns out that only pure production versions behave like described in the documentation. This does not make testing/debugging very developer-friendly...